# I know how to solve equations of $t$, but I'm not sure what $t'$ represents in this equation????

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I am investigating the Wilson Cowan neuron population model, and I can follow most of it, but I'm not sure what is meant by $t'$ in the equation for proportion of neurons in the refractory period. Here is a link to the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%E2%80%93Cowan_model).
The image below is the equation of interest.

[What is $t'$?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9145i.png)

Comment: Your dummy integration variable. It could as well have been $s$ or any other symbol, and carries no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the
"$dt'$"
in the integrals.
This means that
$t'$ is the variable of integration.

Any other variable could be used
as long as it is not used
elsewhere in the expression.

For example,
the first integral
could have been written
$\int_{t-r}^t E(z) dz
$.
The only variables
that could not have been used
as the variable of integration
are $t$ and $r$
since they already have a 
specified meaning.